# How to stop Adobe AIR game for iOS relaunching when re-opened

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I'm making a game with Adobe AIR 16 using FlashDevelop. I want the game to act like other iOS games/apps when closed but still in the background. i.e. when opened again they pick up from where the user left off. Currently if I close my game, it relaunches so I'm back at the menu. Even on the multi-tasking screen I see the splashscreen.

I'm not sure how helpful posting any of my code would be because this seems like a general problem where I just need pointing in the right direction but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to false in you application descriptor.xml

```
<iPhone>
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key><false/>
]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```